# How to form a grid using UITableview?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I am working on TV guide project, I want to know how to form a grid i.e I want to split the cells and construct it just like a grid. I know that I have to use UITableview, but I want to know how to do it.

If any one please provide the concept with sample project or code will be appreciated.

Comment: You can build a custom cell that displays a line of a grid, bur that would be rather ugly. Instead of using a "grid", I'd use a combo approach, with paginating horizontal scroller for navigating my time intervals, and a "plain" `UITableView` for navigating my channels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom cells, each cell with some around 4 to 5 buttons based on your requirement.

I hope you have idea on creating custom table cells & using them.

providing code is bit clumsy thing here

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something like this before, my approach was to subclass `UIScrollView` and implement some custom view recycling and layout. It was pretty simple to implement, although things got a bit complicated when I started implementing animations. Basically, the idea is to override `- (void)layoutSubviews` with something like:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect visibleBounds = [self bounds];

    // calculate the range of visible views

    // recycle any no longer visible views

    // for any missing views, request them from the data source        
 }
```

You will need to implement your own data source and delegate protocols for whatever needs you have, mine were pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of project already exists look into [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).

Answer (score 0):

The Transporter iPhone app does this in a great way; you can check out their code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/ljuba/Transporter-iPhone).

Here's what the tableview looks like in their app:

[image]